# Nested COUNT with WHERE clause in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm a novice in SQL scripts and I trying to get some counts from a table where I count 3 different ways, COUNT(1) is not an issue, but the next two counts are very slow.

There are individual indexes on all columns used in the WHERE clause but still slow. Is there an easier and better way to do these COUNT?

In following code I want to get all unique CustomerID's on each parent-SELECT GROUP BY Timestamp:

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT al2.CustomerID) FROM ActionLog al2
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),al2.Timestamp,110) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),al1.Timestamp,110) and al2.ActionTypeID = al1.ActionTypeID and al2.CampaignID = al1.CampaignID and al2.EventID = al1.EventID and CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al2.URL) > 0 THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al2.URL)-1) ELSE URL END = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL) > 0 THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL)-1) ELSE URL END
AND al2.Timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()),-7) AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()),0)) as Count_Total_DayUnique
```

The next one I want to get all new unique CustomerID's that have not been a part of the parent-SELECT GROUP BY clause before:

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT al3.CustomerID) FROM ActionLog al3
WHERE al3.ActionTypeID = al1.ActionTypeID and al3.CampaignID = al1.CampaignID and al3.EventID = al1.EventID and CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al3.URL) > 0 THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al3.URL)-1) ELSE URL END = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL) > 0 THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL)-1) ELSE URL END
and al3.CustomerID not in (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT al4.CustomerID) FROM ActionLog al4
WHERE al4.ActionTypeID = al1.ActionTypeID and al4.CampaignID = al1.CampaignID and al4.EventID = al1.EventID and CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al4.URL) > 0 THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al3.URL)-1) ELSE URL END = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL) > 0 THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL)-1) ELSE URL END
AND al4.Timestamp > DATEADD(dd, -1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),al1.Timestamp,110)))) as Count_Total_UniqueOnEvent
```

Please see entire script below:

```
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Timestamp,110) as Timestamp
  ,ActivityTypeID
  ,ActionTypeID
  ,CampaignID
  ,EventID
  ,COUNT(1) as Count_Total_Day
  ,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT al2.CustomerID) FROM ActionLog al2
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),al2.Timestamp,110) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),al1.Timestamp,110) and al2.ActionTypeID = al1.ActionTypeID and al2.CampaignID = al1.CampaignID and al2.EventID = al1.EventID and CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al2.URL) > 0 THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al2.URL)-1) ELSE URL END = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL) > 0 THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL)-1) ELSE URL END
    AND al2.Timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()),-7) AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()),0)) as Count_Total_DayUnique
  ,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT al3.CustomerID) FROM ActionLog al3
    WHERE al3.ActionTypeID = al1.ActionTypeID and al3.CampaignID = al1.CampaignID and al3.EventID = al1.EventID and CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al3.URL) > 0 THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al3.URL)-1) ELSE URL END = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL) > 0 THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL)-1) ELSE URL END
    and al3.CustomerID not in (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT al4.CustomerID) FROM ActionLog al4
    WHERE al4.ActionTypeID = al1.ActionTypeID and al4.CampaignID = al1.CampaignID and al4.EventID = al1.EventID and CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al4.URL) > 0 THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al3.URL)-1) ELSE URL END = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL) > 0 THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL)-1) ELSE URL END
    AND al4.Timestamp > DATEADD(dd, -1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),al1.Timestamp,110)))) as Count_Total_UniqueOnEvent
  ,ReportTag
  ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', URL) > 0 THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', URL)-1) ELSE URL END as URL
  ,TemplateID
  FROM ActionLog al1
  WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()),-7) AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()),0)
  GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Timestamp,110),ActivityTypeID,ActionTypeID,CampaignID,EventID,ReportTag,URL,TemplateID
```

I'll try to give you some background on database, sample data and expected result.

Database structure:

```
[dbo].[ActionLog](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Timestamp] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ActionLog]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
[CustomerID] [int] NULL,
[ActivityTypeID] [int] NULL,
[ActionTypeID] [int] NULL,
[CampaignID] [int] NULL,
[EventID] [int] NULL,
[ReportTag] [varchar](500) NULL,
[URL] [varchar](500) NULL,
[TemplateID] [int] NULL,
)
```

Sample:

```
ID  Timestamp   CustomerID  ActivityTypeID  ActionTypeID    CampaignID  EventID ReportTag   URL TemplateID
1   2014-09-24 11:55:27.900 1   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
2   2014-09-24 12:58:26.710 2   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
3   2014-09-24 13:54:34.993 2   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
4   2014-09-24 16:35:33.810 4   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
5   2014-09-24 16:53:17.623 1   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
6   2014-09-25 20:36:30.190 1   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
7   2014-09-25 20:36:33.050 4   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
8   2014-09-25 23:35:38.520 3   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
9   2014-09-25 08:35:15.247 4   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
10  2014-09-25 08:36:11.363 6   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
11  2014-09-26 11:23:58.223 1   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
12  2014-09-26 11:55:12.640 2   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
13  2014-09-26 12:03:28.563 6   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
14  2014-09-26 12:39:53.003 7   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
15  2014-09-26 15:55:55.843 8   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
16  2014-09-27 15:55:55.890 1   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
17  2014-09-27 16:22:05.540 3   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
18  2014-09-27 17:34:43.093 8   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
19  2014-09-27 09:40:23.743 9   1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
20  2014-09-27 10:08:50.240 11  1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
21  2014-09-28 10:12:37.330 11  1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
22  2014-09-28 11:22:26.413 12  1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
23  2014-09-28 11:23:06.520 13  1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
24  2014-09-28 11:52:26.757 14  1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
25  2014-09-28 13:05:13.850 15  1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
26  2014-09-29 13:05:24.900 16  1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
27  2014-09-29 13:06:07.017 16  1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
28  2014-09-29 13:07:26.993 14  1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
29  2014-09-29 14:13:04.893 13  1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
30  2014-09-29 19:54:11.350 12  1   12  35  68  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

My expected result:

```
 Timestamp  ActivityTypeID  ActionTypeID    CampaignID  EventID Count   Count_Total_DayUnique   Count_Total_UniqueOnEvent   Report  Url TemplateID
2014-09-24  1   12  35  68  5   3   3   NULL    NULL    NULL
2014-09-25  1   12  35  68  5   4   2   NULL    NULL    NULL
2014-09-26  1   12  35  68  5   5   2   NULL    NULL    NULL
2014-09-27  1   12  35  68  5   5   3   NULL    NULL    NULL
2014-09-28  1   12  35  68  5   5   4   NULL    NULL    NULL
2014-09-29  1   12  35  68  5   4   1   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I really hope that there are someone that can help me out here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may get better assistance if you can provide table structures, sample data and expected results using that sample data.  My first inclination is that a join instead of a sub query may help, my next is that a window function count(1) over (partition by some fields) may help as well.  but I can't visualize what you're trying to do well enough to see how to build it yet.

Comment: I've just tried to add structure, sample and expected result

Comment: When I remove the last COUNT then it works fairly quick, so that's the one killing my performance it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this subquery:

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT al2.CustomerID)
 FROM ActionLog al2
 WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),al2.Timestamp,110) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),al1.Timestamp,110) and
       al2.ActionTypeID = al1.ActionTypeID and
       al2.CampaignID = al1.CampaignID and
       al2.EventID = al1.EventID and
       (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al2.URL) > 0
             THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al2.URL)-1)
             ELSE URL
        END) = (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL) > 0 
                     THEN LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', al1.URL)-1)
                     ELSE URL
                END) AND
       al2.Timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()),-7) AND DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()),0)
) as Count_Total_DayUnique
```

This is quite complicated.  But you can start with an index on `ActionLog(ActionTypeId, CampaignId, EventId, TimeStamp, url, CustomerId)`.  This should cover the subquery, so only the index would be used for the subquery.

Comment: Just added it, and it seems to be my last COUNT that are killing my performance now.

Comment: One count solved, last count is being updated in a separate update statement